# H2 shell not allowing to select from table

Tags: h2

I run the shell tool of H2:

```
java -cp h2-1.4.199.jar org.h2.tools.Shell
```

I do:

```
sql> show tables
...> ;
TABLE_NAME            | TABLE_SCHEMA
flyway_schema_history | PUBLIC
(1 row, 19 ms)
```

Then I want to select from that table:

```
sql> select * from public.flyway_schema_history;
Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY" not found; SQL statement:
select * from public.flyway_schema_history [42102-199]
```

I tried with out the schema name also, same error.
Why can't it select from that table, when it shows it exists?

Comment: Try `select * from public."flyway_schema_history";`

Comment: That's it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

H2 database is by default case sensitive.

So when you write the table name with lower case letters, and query it without double quotes, it will make it uppercase and try to match it with that.

Since the current table name is lower case you should but it into quotes so that H2 wouldn't force it to uppercase.

`select * from public."flyway_schema_history";`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Why you edited this answer in that way? Identifiers in H2 are case sensitive by default, but unquoted identifiers are converted to upper case by default, they can be considered as case insensitive only when quoted identifiers aren't used. There are three settings (`DATABASE_TO_LOWER`, `DATABASE_TO_UPPER`, and `CASE_INSENSITIVE_IDENTIFIERS`) that control this behavior.

Comment: unquoted identifiers are case insensitive. Only quoted identifiers are case sensitive.

Comment: The first sentence is about the whole database. The names of most objects in the database are case sensitive by default. Unquoted identifiers are case insensitive only when they are compared with other unquoted identifiers, in other contexts they are converted to upper case and then compared in case-sensitive way (by default). So if there is an object with lower case character(s) it cannot be accessed with an unquoted identifier (by default), the name of the object and the specified unquoted identifier aren't compared in case insensitive way.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Good I felt the same way. Right now it feels like you can write `tabel_name` and it equals `TABEL_NAME` I'll roll back the edit.

Comment: With default settings `table_name`, `TABLE_NAME`, `Table_Name`, etc., and `"TABLE_NAME"` are identical (and they all persisted as `"TABLE_NAME"`), but `"table_name"` is a different name.